# how to parse a date from string in hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have some scv input data files, which look like this:

```
TicketID,AccountID,DateOpened
1,acc-1,2015-10-29 T 10:45 UTC
2,acc-2,2015-10-29 T 10:45 UTC
3,acc-1,2015-10-30 T 10:45 UTC
```

Is there a way to have Hive parse the DateOpened field as a Date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try simple and very handy `TO_DATE`

```
select TO_DATE(DateOpened) from tablename;
```

output:-

```
2015-10-29
2015-10-29
2015-10-30
```

Comment: I thought that wouldn't work because the time stamp string was in a different format than they call out in the documentation but sure enough it does work. I should have tested it with "select to_date('2015-10-29 T 10:45 UTC')".

Answer (score 1):

You can use a substr function to grab the date from your timestamp and then cast it as a date data type.

```
select cast(substr(DateOpened,1,10) as date) from yourTableName
```